# how to save an image from video/quicktime video?

Tags: php, video, quicktime

Hello is there a way in PHP to save an image from video/quicktime video ?

Comment: Please add more info. Where is the video located, is it a file or a stream? What kind of server are you on? What kind of quicktime video is it (Exact format)?

Comment: @Pekka it's a .mov file located on the server and the server is linux but i'm not sure about the server because i'm making a product which should run on multiple servers !

Comment: PHP is Hypertext Preprocessor. Remember that. No cofemachine or videoeditor included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in pure PHP. You would have to use an external command line tool like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) - but that makes the script less portable to other servers.

The only other idea that comes to mind is the [Snapshot plugin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/96/Snapshot?q=) to the LongTail Video player. With that, you can manually send snapshots of a video playing in the video player (an embeddable Flash player) to a server side script. The process can't be automated, though, and the video will need to be a FLV or MP4 one for this to work.